# How to remove “Decimal” from the query result in python

Tags: python

I have this code :

```
sql = "SELECT AVG(status = 2)*100 AS percentagem FROM voosinfo WHERE Date = %s"
cursor.execute(sql, (user_input,))

records = cursor.fetchone()
print(records)
```

Comment: `print(int(records))`?

Comment: Also, please see [mcve].

Comment: @roganjosh That is probably not what the asker wants

Comment: I assume your code queries a SQLite DB, but please include some helpful context. Also, example of the output is helpful.

Comment: thanks i have  resolve

Answer (score 0):

Python has two ways of formatting objects as strings, one is the `str` method and one is the `repr` method. The `str` value is meant to be the human readable representation of the object, while the `repr` value is meant as a more complete debug representation.

When printing a string, it will print the `str` value. However, the `fetchone` method likely returns a tuple or a list. For these types, the `str` representation will include the `repr` representation of all the items.

It is up to you to format the string, but if you want e.g. a comma separated list, try

```
print(', '.join(records))
```

or if you know you have a single record, try

```
record, = records
print(record)
```

Comment: Based on your comment to me under the main question, I don't think this is what they want, either, but I see your line. If they are getting a `Decimal` object then that could be well be that the column type is translated to that... then they somehow inadvertently convert to a string

Comment: If this solved your issue please consider marking this as the correct answer